# How Could I Have Caught 400 & Only Seen 399?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

My dex in SWSH looks like this:

> [image]

and says:

> Caught: 400
> Seen: 399

I'm not sure how it is even possible to have caught more Pokemon than I have seen.

I am also not seeing any greyed-out entries, i.e.: unseen Pokemon, in my dex.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you transfer any Pokemon from Pokemon Home?

Comment: People on Reddit had this bug with Eternatus. Have you fought it yet?

Comment: Everything was transferred through Home - from myself to myself - I only have one gym badge on this save ATM.

Comment: I wonder if your starter counts as a "caught" but not seen?

Comment: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonSwordAndShield/comments/vr03rw/anyone_ever_seen_this_before_400_caught_but_399/) Reddit thread (perhaps the same one that Pinkerman was looking at) implies this is a display bug with transferring Pokémon in from home. Some people encountered it with Eternatus, others Polteageist

Comment: @Wondercricket yep, that's it. And considering OP has only one badge, I'm confident that Eternatus is the one missing

Answer (score 1):

From comments and [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonSwordAndShield/comments/vr03rw/anyone_ever_seen_this_before_400_caught_but_399/), this is likely due to either Eternatus or transferring in something from Pokemon Home messing the numbers up.